# angularjs translate can't use with angular ui router?

Tags: angularjs

I am new with Angularjs

and I want to use angular-translate

here is the site

http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/

I refer it document , and I got the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'useStaticFilesLoader' of undefined from remoteApp
```

here is my code

**app.js**

```
angular.module('remoteApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'ngResource', 'truncate',    
  'pascalprecht.translate'])
  .config(['$translateProvider', function ($routeProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,      
    $translateProvider) {

$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
  prefix: 'languange/locale-',
  suffix: '.json'
});

$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
$translateProvider.useLocalStorage();


$stateProvider
.state('index', {
    url: "",
    views: {
        "viewA": {
            templateUrl: "views/main.html",
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        },
        "viewB": {
            templateUrl: "views/appList.html",
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        },
        "viewC": {
            templateUrl: "views/appTree.html",
            controller: 'ApptreeCtrl'
        }
    },

})

.state('applicatoion', {
    url: "/applicatoion",
    views: {
        "viewA": {
            templateUrl: "views/main.html",
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        },
        "viewB": {
            templateUrl: "views/appList.html",
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        },
        "viewC": {
            templateUrl: "views/appTree.html",
            controller: 'ApptreeCtrl'
        }
    }
})}]);
```

I have no idea about it ,

please help

Answer (score 2):

Right now this is how you are calling .config

```
config(['$translateProvider', function ($routeProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,      
    $translateProvider) {
    // ...
}]);
```

.config has its parameters ( dependencies ) injected by AngularJS, there are two ways to call config;

1 - Pass in a function and AngularJS will read the parameter names and find the matching dependencies.
2 - Pass in an array, of which the last item is a function, and the other items are names of dependencies, if you use this, AngularJS will not read the function's parameter names. The reason this exists is so you can minify your code; because minifying would change the parameter names, and AngularJS uses those names to find dependencies.

What you have now is you specify only one dependency, `'$translateProvider'`, which means the first parameter being passed to the function is the translateProvider, and the other parameters end up being undefined, because you didn't ask for more dependencies.

What you can do is either let AngularJS read your dependency names like this

```
config(function ($routeProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider) {
    // ...
});
```

Or you can specify all of the dependencies, matching the function parameter list like this, allowing you ( only if you do this consistently ) to minify your code without breaking it.

```
config(['$routeProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$translateProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider) {
        // ...
}]);
```

Comment: the first way , will show the error "Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $translateLocalStorageProvider <- $translateLocalStorage <- $translate ", and second way will show the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<$RouteProvider> has no method 'useStaticFilesLoader' from remoteApp"

Comment: If you want to do `$translateProvider.useLocalStorage();` you need to include the translate local storage provider yourself, this is a separate script. See https://github.com/PascalPrecht/angular-translate/wiki/Installation#installing-dependencies For the second error, create a chat and show your current code?

Comment: for the $translateProvider.useLocalStorage(); I have embed the 'angular-translate-loader-static-files.js'

Comment: Updated the chat; you were still not calling .config correctly